# Insert complex HTML with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to insert HTML like this with jQuery:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is <a href="somewhere">simply dummy</a> text of the printing and typesetting industry.<span style="color:red; font-size: 1.6rem;">*</span> <p>
```

I try with this but it only works without `<a>` and `<span>` but in console this return **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

```
jQuery("div#webform-component-consent > .description").html(<p>Lorem Ipsum is 
<a href="somewhere">simply dummy</a> 
text of the printing and typesetting industry.
<span style="color:red; font-size: 1.6rem;">*</span>
</p>);
```

I also try with **.append()** but the result is the same. Do you think this is possible and how?

Comment: Try calling with a string instead.

Comment: wrap it with single qoute like `'<p>Lorem Ipsum is 
<a href="somewhere">simply dummy</a> 
text of the printing and typesetting industry.
<span style="color:red; font-size: 1.6rem;">*</span>
</p>'`

Comment: If you want to keep the newlines you need to wrap in  ` backticks

Comment: Please check the [official docs](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).  You would have spotted this a lot sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove line breaks and put it inside quotes.

```js
jQuery("div#webform-component-consent > .description").html('<p>Lorem Ipsum is <a href="somewhere">simply dummy</a> text of the printing and typesetting industry. <span style="color:red; font-size: 1.6rem;">*</span></p>');
```

```html
<div id="webform-component-consent">
  <div class="description"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this;

```
var htmlString = `<p>Lorem Ipsum is <a href="somewhere">simply dummy</a> text of the printing and typesetting industry.<span style="color:red; font-size: 1.6rem;">*</span> <p>
`;

// you can choose your element, for sake of example we are using P tag;

$("p").append(htmlString);
```

Comment: Why not `$("div#webform-component-consent > .description").html(htmlString)` but also why answer at all. It is voted down and almost closed

Comment: answered to help him, i guess this is a platform to learn from each other right? 

and i chose not to spoon feed but to show him the way.

Comment: by the way @mplungjan has explained it in comments of question also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string between ` i.e. [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) so that you can use multi-line strings and " (double quote) inside string.

```js
jQuery("div#webform-component-consent > .description").html(`<p>Lorem Ipsum is 
<a href="somewhere">simply dummy</a> 
text of the printing and typesetting industry.
<span style="color:red; font-size: 1.6rem;">*</span>
</p>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="webform-component-consent">
  <div class="description">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use InnerHTML and "\" before double quotes:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("analyseButtonImage")[i].innerHTML = "<p>Lorem Ipsum is <a href=\"somewhere\">simply dummy</a> text of the printing and typesetting industry.<span style=\"color:red; font-size: 1.6rem;\">*</span> <p>";
```